# Background video that acts like CSS' background size cover of an element, not entire page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to code up a new site where there's a big splash background as a "hero" image. Like this site has, *but* as a video where the image is of the lady unloading the car: https://www.simple.com

Resize and you can see how the image always fits within it's parent.

I put some of the code I've been working on in JSBin here (not making much progress): http://jsbin.com/ruqisa/1/edit

I can't seem to get that same behavior with CSS. I want the video to spill outside the parent either width or height wise depending on the dimensions of the screen.

Has anyone done this with pure CSS? JS I could calculate it manually on resize, but I'd really love to do this with just CSS.

EDIT: I'm not looking for the entire page to be a video, just the header background.

Comment: [Like this example?](http://jsbin.com/rabaki/1/edit?css,output) (sort of?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's adapt the technique [outlined on the blog demosthenes.info](http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video).

### Option 1 — Scroll with the page

The parent div:

- is given a fixed height and `overflow: hidden`

The video:

- is stretched with `min-width: 100%` and `min-height: 100%`
- is placed behind content with `z-index: -1` (can be any negative number)

To center the video:

- `top` and `left` are set to `50%` which places the top-left corner in the middle of the parent div
- the video is offset by half the height and width by dragging it halfway up and to the left with `transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);`

#### Simplified example

[Here is a full demo with all your markup.](http://jsbin.com/wiwovu/2/edit)

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <video autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

### 2 — Fixed full page background

The video:

- doesn't need a wrapper, it can be placed anywhere on the page
- is made `position: fixed` and will position itself in relation to the browser window (viewport)
- is stretched with `min-width: 100%` and `min-height: 100%`
- is placed behind content with `z-index: -1` (can be any negative number)

To center the video:

- `top` and `left` are set to `50%` which places the top-left corner in the middle of the screen
- the video is offset by half the height and width by dragging it halfway up and to the left with `transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);`

#### Simplified example

[Here is a full demo with all your markup.](http://jsbin.com/tujogo/1/edit)

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 600px;
}
video.background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h1>I am content</h1>
<p>I am content too!</p>
<video class="background" autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: This is a great technique, and I'm glad you posted it. Just for clarification for others though, it's not what the question was asking for, and can only take the entire viewport as its container rather than an individual element, and will stay fixed when scrolling.

Comment: What @stvnrynlds said. :) If you go to the Simple link the header "hero" image takes up a set height. In this case, .big-splash would be the container and I'd want it to do like what yours is doing scaling on the whole body, but within that that .big-splash element. I don't want the video to take up the entire page but just the entire element.

Comment: You're right, of course :) - [how about this example?](http://jsbin.com/tujogo/2/edit) with `position: absolute` it will scroll

Comment: @stvnrynlds and Oscar, I think the new example I added provides what you are after.

Comment: How to put a footer content that "pushes" the video and make it like 80% height (keeping center focus and 100% witdth ) ?
hope I explained :)

Answer (score 2):

```
.big-splash video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: url(some.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/lunarugibe/1/**

**Source: [Create Fullscreen HTML5 Page Background Video](http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video)**

The video is first positioned absolutely then centered using `top`, `left` and `transform` properties along the X and Y axis. That -webkit- vendor prefix is for safari ([Can I use... Support tables for HTML5, CSS3, etc](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)).

The `min-height` and `min-width` properties force smaller resolution video to occupy the whole page.

The `background` property gives a preview image until the video is ready to be played. `background: cover` is for this preview image, to make it occupy the full area.

and the `z-index` value makes sure that the video is behind all other elements.

Comment: This is actually the right answer, but at least [credit the source](http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video) if you are going to copy paste the snippet. You could also explain how it works.

Comment: I am sorry, I was editing. I always include Source whenever applicable.

Comment: That's close, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. If you go to the Simple link the header "hero" image takes up a set height. In this case, `.big-splash` would be the container and I'd want it to do _like_ what yours is doing scaling on the whole body, but within that that `.big-splash` element. I don't want the video to take up the entire page but just the entire element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this affect with pure CSS pretty easily:

```
.container {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

If you want to keep it centered or do a full screen video, you will probably need to use some Javascript for calculating window heights.